# Did not work django-filters in Django app

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am trying to use django filters for my application, but it always returns the same error.

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Promoters
ImportError: cannot import name 'Promoters' from 'django.contrib.auth.models' (C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\my_app\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py)
```

Has anyone had a similar problem? How best to solve it? change of django versia? 
or maybe there are any alternatives?

My django version (2, 1, 2, 'final', 0), Python 3.6.

EDIT: 
I am trying to add a search engine to my site, well i installed 'pip install django-filter' and added this to my settings.py. Next i created filters.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Promoters
import django_filters

class PromotersFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Promoters
        fields = ['age', 'profession', 'sex', 'city']
```

for my models.py

```
class Promoters(models.Model):
    MEAN = 'M'
    WOMAN = 'W'
    SEX = (
        (MEAN, 'Mean'),
        (WOMAN, 'Woman'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                          MaxValueValidator(99)])
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX, default=MEAN) 
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hobby = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number_friends = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    related_brands = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                         MaxValueValidator(10)])
    user_group = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    activities_month = models.IntegerField()
    fb_links = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and also create a views.py

```
def Promotors(request):
    #promoters
    campaignlist = Campaign.objects.filter(customer_name=request.user)
    promoters_list = Promoters.objects.all()
    #search rama
    promoters_filter = PromotersFilter(request.GET, queryser=promoters_list)
    #context
    context = { 'campaignlist':campaignlist, 'filter':promoters_filter}
    return render(request, 'account/costumer_profile.html', context)
```

Then when I try to start the server, I get an error: 'ImportError:...'

On other forums there is information that this may be due to the mismatch of django-filters to the django version. 
But I did not find any information on how to solve this problem to implement the search engine.

Comment: I've never heard of such a model in Django, and google isn't turning up any references either. Are you sure this model isn't one from one of your own apps - or possibly some 3rd-party library - and that you're trying to import it from the wrong place?

Comment: You are using `Promoter` as your user class. Right?

Comment: here is the [django.contrib.auth.models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py).

Comment: I added the extension of my question above.

Comment: So `Promoter` is your own model, as I suspected. So don't try to import it from `django.contrib.auth.models` - where it doesn't exist and therefore throws the error you see. Import it from `<your_app_name>.models`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it solved my problem.